# SFunction memory violation

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink, mex, s-function

I am writting a S Function that outputs a array of boolean (4 positions)

I am having a access memmory violation while writing the outputs inside mdlOutputs callback.

This error is not instantenous. I mean: the code runs fine until it crashes later on and Matlab gives a fatal error. I'm pretty sure the error is in the memcpy operation because I have debugged and after I comment this line of code, it works fine. Also, it runs 100% fine if the data type is a scalar.

So, I have a couple of questions:

1. How can I use memcpy to write the values of an array in simulink?
2. I have assumed that simulink output memmory is a continuous memmory block. Is it correct?
3. Any hints on how to solve it?

Pseudo-Code is here:

```
static void mdlOutputs ( SimStruct* S, int_T tid ) {
(...)
//src variable defined here
(...)

void* dst;

// get output port data type id
type = ssGetOutputPortDataType ( S, i );  // type = SS_BOOLEAN

// get data type size
size = ssGetDataTypeSize ( S, type );   //size = 1 byte

// get output port signal pointer
dst = ( void* ) ssGetOutputPortSignal ( S, i );  //dst has a valid value

// get output port width
width = ssGetOutputPortWidth ( S, i );  //width is 4, since it is a 4 position array

size = size * width; // size now is 4

memcpy ( dst, src, size );     // Error
}
```

Comment: Are you getting anything from an input port?  You haven't shown that bit of code, but you may need to be using [ssSetInputPortRequiredContiguous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/sssetinputportrequiredcontiguous.html).

Comment: I´m not 100% sure, but it seems that input port is OK, and the problem is while writing to the SFunction Outport.  I am able to get all data  from the input and parse it to the correct type. I googled it but I couldn´t find a  ssSet_OUTPUT_PortRequiredContiguous method. There must be a logical reason for that.

Comment: Do I need to get pointers to the output with ssGetOutputPortSignal ? What if input port number 5 is an array?

Comment: For your src input port, is the size, type and width identical to your output port i?

Comment: I encountered a similar problem when using an S-function that was compiled in an older version of Matlab.